# Azure Mobile service for persistent data from my Android app, does not work

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I need help, seems like a simple problem, but I'm stuck with it is several days. I am trying to use Azure Mobile service for persisting data from my Android app. The issue I am having now is that I have a data transfer object with several fields corresponding to columns in Azure database table. It is a simple table, followed all the steps ... What am I doing wrong?

```
    package com.bn7.rotabn7;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.*;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private MobileServiceClient mClient;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            try {
                 mClient = new MobileServiceClient( 
                        "https://ocamorana.azure-mobile.net/", 
                        "hCzcrsFYhkGmxPvQDNxyqBXjZwjXlK99", 
                        this 
                        );
                Item item = new Item(); 
                item.IdPhone = "Awesome item"; 
                item.DateTimePhone = "Awesome item"; 
                item.LatitudePhone = -43; 
                item.LongetudePhone = -23; 
                item.ActivePhone = false; 
                mClient.getTable(Item.class).insert(item, new TableOperationCallback<Item>() {
                     public void onCompleted(Item entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) { 
                        if (exception == null) { 
                             // Insert succeeded 
                                                } else { 
                             // Insert failed
                            Log.d("Insert failed", "*---------------------------------------------------------------*");
                            Log.d("Insert failed", "Error in activity", exception);  // log the error
                            Log.d("Insert failed", "*---------------------------------------------------------------*");
                        } 
                     } 
                });
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.d("MalformedURLException", e.toString());
            }
    }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }

    package com.bn7.rotabn7;

    public class Item { 
        public int Id; 
        public String IdPhone;
        public String DateTimePhone;
        public double LatitudePhone;
        public double LongetudePhone;
        public boolean ActivePhone;
        }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bn7.rotabn7"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.bn7.rotabn7.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

> Error in activity
>       om.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: Error while processing request.
>       com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceConnection$1.onNext(MobileServiceConnection.java:121)
>       com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient$4.handleRequest(MobileServiceClient.java:429)
>       com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceConnection.start(MobileServiceConnection.java:92)
>       com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:77)
>       com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:1)
>       android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>       java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>       java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
>       Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ocamorana.azure-mobile.net
>       java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
>       java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
>       java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
>       org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
>       org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>       org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>       org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
>       org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>       org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>       org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>       com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.ServiceFilterRequestImpl.execute(ServiceFilterRequestImpl.java:73)
>       com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceConnection$1.onNext(MobileServiceConnection.java:101)
>       *---------------------------------------------------------------*

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that you're missing the Internet permission from your manifest (as it's complaining about UnknownHost which is usually an indicator that the app can't connect to the internet).  Make sure this is in your manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback, sorry I had not put together the code of manifest, but was already allowed to the Internet, seems to me to be correct. Does not work ... :-(

Comment: The error indicates that it can't actually connect to the service.  What happens if you open the browser on the emulator and try to connect to https://ocamorana.azure-mobile.net/.  Try creating a new emulator and see if you get the same UnknownHostException.

Comment: Again thanks for the feedback. As you indicated I created another mobile service, mClient = new MobileServiceClient ("https://bn7.azure-mobile.net/" ... resulted in exactly the same effect. Testing with the example of the Azure ToDo and both services (ocamorana and BN7) function. With my code that is simpler not work.

Comment: Testing services using the Browser both up and running.

Comment: Try unzipping this project and importing it into Eclipse: http://storage.chrisrisner.com/codesamples/AndroidConnectTest.zip.  I just tested with the code as is against a live Mobile Service and everything works fine.  Can you edit your answer to include your manifest?

Comment: the application you sent test worked perfectly, the problem should really be with my application, sorry if I'm asking too much, but here's my application; https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=3CF3FC770FC59E9B&resid=3CF3FC770FC59E9B!1277&authkey=ADQMeBtUVTTIjtE%22

Comment: Both the example sent to me as an example I downloaded the site work correctly, but my application is much simpler, does not work, because I really do not understand step by step what is described in the documentation, checked the libraries, manifest, the code, everything seems to be correct. I do not understand what is wrong.

Comment: It was permissions issue on the table. Resolved, thanks Chris :-)

Comment: FWIW and for anyone else that might find this, you may have been having permission issues as well but in the case above, that is not the error you were receiving.  UnknownHostException is not the error you get when you have permission issues, that is specifically if you cannot hit the internet endpoint.  Per your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794107/security-error-to-persist-data-in-azure-with-an-android-app) you would have received Unauthorized if the issue was permissions on the table, not UnknownHostException.